# Error when consuming Remote EJB in JavaDelegate - Activiti

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, alfresco, activiti

I've the following problem:

I need to use an EJB Remote from a class that implements JavaDelegate of Activity (alfresco).

This happens when my Work Flow arrives at a ServiceTask (I'm using "Task Type": ExpressionDelegate but it also happens with "Task Type": Class), this task uses a FooDelegate and in this class it contains an EJB that I can not use it, it always gives me the NullPointerException error when I use the EJB.

[image]

In Properties of the Service Task is:
[image]

But also used "Task Type: Class"

My code of HelloWorldBean is:

```
    @Stateless
    public class DemoImpl implements JavaDelegate {

        @EJB(name = "FooServ")
        private FooInterface fooServ;

        @Override
        public void execute(DelegateExecution execute) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(">>>> hello world my name is " + fooServ.getNameDefault() + " <<<<");
        }
    }
```

in my file "Activiti.cfg.xml" it has this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
  ...
  ..

  <bean id="HelloWordBean" class="com.development.workflow.HelloWordClass"/>
  <jee:remote-slsb id="FooServ" resource-ref="false" business-interface="com.production.FooInterface" jndi-name="java:global/production-ejb/FooServ" />

  ..
  ...

</beans>
```

I also declare my remote ejb in the jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="8.0" xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_8_0.xsd">
  <context-root>/demo</context-root>
  <virtual-host>demo-host</virtual-host>
  <security-domain>demo-realm</security-domain>
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/demo</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>java:/platform/jdbc/demo-flow</jndi-name>
  </resource-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>FooServ</ejb-ref-name> 
    <jndi-name>java:/production/FooServ</jndi-name>
  </ejb-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

As you can see, declare in the two xml files the FooServ Remote EJB, but I can not get it to work, I always get the JavaNullPointerException error in the line where I use the Remote EJB.

The code of my EJB Remote is:

```
package com.production;

public interface FooInterface {

  String getNameDefault();

}    


package com.production.Impl;

import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@Local(FooInterface.class)
public class FooImplement implements FooInterface {

  @Override
  public String getNameDefault() {
    return "I am EJB remote";
  }

}
```

I am using wildfly 10, jee7, activiti 5.2.2.

How can I use that EJB in my project? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I think the reason you're getting a NPE is that your delegate is not being instantiated as an actual EJB, but as a regular class. Replace the EJB annotation by @Autowired and see if you still get the NPE

Comment: I still give myself NPE, even though I add the annotation @Autowired, I also try to call a BEAN that has an EJB inside it. Call bean correctly but the EJB that has inside it the exception NPE does not work

Comment: Did you try to do the ejb lookup explicitly, instead of using injection ?

Comment: Yes, I still give myself NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @Philippe, I implemented an explicit lookup (using the JNDI) and this worked for me correctly. The code that I use is:

```
public FooService getEJB() {
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        Object obj = ctx.lookup("java:/production/FooServ");
        return (FooService) obj;
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```